# Windows 10 turn all app window background to black

Tags: windows-10

I don't remember what did I do before, but it change all window 's background to black
I've tried google a lot but don't know the best issue question to ask, so I decided to go to SO to ask
[Screenshot error app background turn to black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeHrN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You’ve probably turned on “dark mode” for Apps. Type “dark mode” in the search bar and look for “Turn on dark mode for apps” or something similar.

Then set the “default app mode” to “light” again.

This works for Windows 10 build 1903. If I recall correctly, build 1809 works in a similar way.

Comment: I've try all settings, but nothing change. [Image](https://imgur.com/7ZjA05P)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I 've solved this.

Because I run some C++ code that make SysColor change, then it change all other application.

```cpp
    // This code will apply all windows app
    int aElements[2] = {COLOR_WINDOW, COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION};
    DWORD aOldColors[2];
    DWORD aNewColors[2];

    aOldColors[0] = GetSysColor(aElements[0]);
    aOldColors[1] = GetSysColor(aElements[1]);
    aNewColors[0] = RGB(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);  // light gray
    aNewColors[1] = RGB(0x00, 0x00, 0x00);  // dark purple

    SetSysColors(2, aElements, aNewColors);
    //    SetSysColors(2, aElements, aOldColors);
```

Just changed `0x00` to `0xFF`